# Set null value in Filter Lookup field in dynamic 365

Tags: javascript, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, lookupfield

In my D365 Project I want to set "No Record Found" in filter lookup field.

I have created lookup field. In that field I called JavaScript and filter that lookup which is working properly but when records are empty it was showing error like "0x80041103 Query Builder Error". When I check fetch xml in 'fetch Xml Tester' it was showing 0 records but it's shows error on lookup field.

Here I attach screenshot of error for your reference.

[image]

Here is my view of lookup field

[image]

Comment: most probably your custom view for lookup is broken or not correct. check your view in view designer or use view replicator in xrmtoolbox

Comment: @AnkUser I have updated my question. I have added the screenshot of view of lookup field.

Comment: could you check whether your filter in JS or your customer Asset lookup View have any deleted column or something? Also could you add code of you js it will be helpful